# Google maps delegates called incorrectly in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, delegates

We noticed that `idleAtCameraPosition` is being called way before it should be in v2.0.1 of the iOS Google Maps SDK.

Is this a bug?

Fact: Calls to `didChangeCameraPosition` continue, even after `idleAtCameraPosition` is called. To add insult to injury, it calls `idleAtCameraPosition` with the incorrect "resting" position.

So, pretty sure this is a bug.

Comment: idleAtCameraPosition Says that it will be called when you stop moving your camera. so pretty in your case is it called On the Way when You Move

Comment: Yes, as you told.